# How does Googlebot index AngularJS Applications

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, googlebot

I'm developing some little Anglur applications. And I have some questions about how Googlebot can index my page and the content loaded via Ajax.

What I've found:

- [Tests about indexing Javascript - searchengineland.com](http://searchengineland.com/tested-googlebot-crawls-javascript-heres-learned-220157)
- [Precomposing a SPA - analog-ni.co](http://www.analog-ni.co/precomposing-a-spa-may-become-the-holy-grail-to-seo)
- [Google index AngularJS - stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27849927/google-indexing-of-my-angularjs-application)

What I get from these 3 links is that Google is able to index Javascript. It is able to follow links and content published on these links. But Google is not able to read content loaded via Ajax (because the scripts are interpreted immediatly after fetching them).

And if an Angular Application should be indexed you have to make sure that:

- You use html5-Mode for routing
- You offer a sitemap with all routes
- Dynamically loaded content has to change the route, otherwise Google won't be able to index it

---

But I still have some open Questions about Googlebot indexing Javascript and AngularJS:

1. Google offers the "Fetch as Google"-Service. If you let Google index your page with that service, is **this** Googlebot able to index Javascript or is this like the **old** Googlebot?
2. Do you need to tell Googlebot to index you Javascript or will this happen automatically (like "oh there's some Javascript, let's index that!")
3. Had anyone some successful expiriences with Googlebot and indexing AngularJS? If so please give me some advise.

I think this is a really new topic with Googlebot indexing Javascript, especially AngularJS and I didn't found really helpful information on the internet. So it would be great if you can answer my open questions, but better would be, if you can just write the experiences you had about that topic.

I know it's possible to offer Google HTML-Snapshots which will be indexed - but I hope this isn't the final solution and it's possible to let Googlbot directly index your Javascript-Content

Comment: take a look at https://prerender.io/

Comment: If you are looking for definitive answers I really doubt you will get them here on SO and should follow guidelines set by the search engines themselves.  As for `fetch as google` ... why can't you test that yourself?