# Angular:-Save Angular js file as a Html file and push the file on server

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, file, gruntjs

A simple question..

I have to save some specific contents(body) of an angular file and then save the file as an HTML file if possible..Also as soon as the file is saved want to push it to the server..

Any idea about how to implement the above..

Is snapshot feature I read about in some tutorials using Grunt help me achieve the same (https://github.com/cburgdorf/grunt-html-snapshot)..

Just wanted to understand what's the best way to implement the same and whether it is possible to do so..Thanks for the help

Comment: Do you want to prepare your site for web crawlers? Something like [prerender.io](https://prerender.io/) offers?

Comment: @fracz Yes I do and want to make it SEO enabled so it doesn't affect other parameters already on the site..Any idea regarding the same

Comment: Does [Google indexing of my AngularJS application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27849927/google-indexing-of-my-angularjs-application) help you?

Comment: @fracz thats the later part..First part is how do I save the HTML page and send it to a server