# What is the status of Angularjs SEO in 2018?

Tags: angularjs

I remade my website, and used angularJS for some part of it. It is online for three weeks now, and seems that Google still not indexed any of the angularjs content.

I would like to know what is the status of Google crawling Angularjs in 2018?

Searching the web returns old articles that claims that Google cannot crawl Angularjs, although google claim they do crawl Angularjs.

Should I wait patiently for Google to crawl my site or generate a server-side-rendering instead?

Also, I would like a link to how to properly do server-side-rendering in 2018?
Is hashbang is still the standard way to do it? There are [some similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27849927/google-indexing-of-my-angularjs-application) on Stack Overflow that are several years old, but I wonder if the situation has changed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google indexing of my AngularJS application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27849927/google-indexing-of-my-angularjs-application)

Comment: in general nothing has changed dramatically since then.
maybe google understands JS code slightly better but you still need to provide it with sitemap - google is not going to click every single pixel expecting some navigation(also it does not send forms - only direct links are indexed while processing the content).

Comment: skyboyer, do you have a reference for this statement? I found it very hard to belief that there is no dramatically changes in 3 years

Comment: (Please don't add meta and voting commentary into questions - add it to the comments if you like, but it's not of interest to most readers, who do not even sign in).

Comment: According to SO, if you want to state that a question is not duplicate you must edit the question, therefore I had to add it to the question

Comment: Ah, you're right Elia - my apologies. I've added a note back in. As an editor I see voting commentary being added to questions (please don't downvote me, please upvote this if it was useful, please don't downvote without commenting, this is not a duplicate [no reason given]) and much of it is not actually useful question material. I tend to excise most of that stuff, but yes, the UI does ask for it in this case. (Btw, use `@halfer` to ping me please - only just chanced upon your reply).

Answer (score 3):

here is a good article - http://kevinmichaelcoy.com/blog/2018/02/19/2018-search-engine-optimization-with-angularjs-1-x-single-page-application/

> Also, for your sanity, you can check what your website looks like when Google crawls it by going to Google Webmaster/Search Console and under “Crawl” choose “Fetch as Google”, then “Fetch and Render” :
>
> https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/googlebot-fetch

In the case of my site - google doesn't index angular JS so well

For some page it display the content as I would expected, but on other it just display the raw html (i.e. with the {{title}} ng tag instead of the value of the $scope.title)

I'm fetching a category page that uses ajax to display the category content - some category display well, thus it might be a bug in the googlebot-fetch tool

https://buyamerica.co.il/ba_supplier#/showCategory/ba-suplier/840

[image]

https://buyamerica.co.il/ba_supplier#/showCategory/ba-suplier/468

[image]

But I still don't know how long should it take for google to show it in the index?

NOTE: according to this https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html server side rendering is deprecated

Comment: so how it looks for google? does it fail to retrieve pages? or does it seem google does not execute javascript code? do you provide google with sitemap or rely google should run js-based navigation?

Comment: I provide a site map. google still doesn't index NG as of today